# How do I register for systemd service lifecycle events?

Tags: go, dbus, systemd

I want to be informed about all state changes of service units. I know there is the DBUS API which gives me signals for UnitNew and UnitRemoved, but the semantic is still unclear to me. Also the signals doesn't provide the informations I need.

I'm using go and tried the [go-systemd lib](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd) from coreos. They provide a way to "subscribe" but it's in fact polling all the unit information available in the system. I do not want to do so every few milliseconds, just to get informed about statechanges.

I also tried the default org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties but I can not get this working.

Please help If you can, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [systemd APIs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/InterfacePortabilityAndStabilityChart/) that contain information about the start or stop of service units are:

- The systemd journal. You can listen to it by executing [journalctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) or forwarding it via network to your program or watching for changes to the files on disk. E.g.: execute `journalctl --follow -o json-pretty _PID=1` (you can add various filters like `UNIT=gdm.service` to only get those for one service) and then parse `stdout` according to the [systemd journal json output format](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/json/) to get the journal messages of systemd. Use the `MESSAGE_ID` to match what the event means and watch for unknown messages to know when an existing message got replaced with a new one. While this might work robustly enough, log messages are not primarily intended as an API. As such I would recommend to use the below options.
- [Linux cgroup notifications](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt?id=b340959ea281dbac15344277094d0a294dbe8aca#n204) as they get generated when [systemd uses cgroups](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) to start a service.
- [systemd units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) via their dependencies (like `Wants=`)